# Cannot read property 'log' of undefined Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope this one isnt too obvious but im needing a sanity check, I have looked at a few other similar posts but I cant seem to find the error. THe service and the consuming controller below.

Service

```
(function() {   
var notify = function(){    
    var logIt;
  toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width",
    "timeOut": "10000"
  };
  logIt = function(message, type) {
    return toastr[type](message);
  };
  return {
    log: function(message) {
      logIt(message, 'info');
    },
    logWarning: function(message) {
      logIt(message, 'warning');
    },
    logSuccess: function(message) {
      logIt(message, 'success');
    },
    logError: function(message) {
      logIt(message, 'error');
    }
  };
};
var module = angular.module("app");
module.factory("notify",notify);
}());
```

Controller

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module("app");
var LoginController = function($scope, $interval, $location,ucja,notify) {   
$scope.client = ucja;
$scope.login = function(user,pass){
 notify.log("Heads up! This alert needs your attention, but it's not super important.");
    };   
  };
app.controller("LoginController",['$scope','notify',LoginController]);
}());
```

Comment: You inject scope and notify in your array constructor for your controller but your controller takes 5 arguments, notify being the last one which will be undefined.

Comment: Your dependencies listed in the controller does not match (order and number must be same) arguments in the constructor. `app.controller("LoginController",['$scope', '$interval', '$location','ucja','notify',LoginController]);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you fiskers and PSL! It was my ignorance that didnt know order counted. That actually ended up solving problems all across the baord for me.
I changed to

```
var LoginController = function($scope,notify,ucja)
app.controller("LoginController",['$scope','notify','ucja',LoginController]);
```

Good to go! Hope this can help someone else learning angular for the firs time.